# Kudan for Unity v1.1.3 : Crash on Android/Unable to start application

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan

I have installed Kudan 1.1.3 in Unity 5.3.4. I have followed 100% accurately the scene setup from Kudan's "getting started" guide. I hit "build and run", everything looks OK but once starting on Nexus 9, the app dies immediately. I generated a bug report with ADB and here is the crash narrowed to whatever seemed to me relevant :

```
05-24 13:38:28.619  5751  5777 E Unity   : [KudanAR] Graphics vendor: NVIDIA Corporation

05-24 13:38:28.619  5751  5777 E Unity   :  

05-24 13:38:28.619  5751  5777 E Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

05-24 13:38:28.619  5751  5777 E Unity   : 

05-24 13:38:28.620  5751  5777 E Unity   : [KudanAR] Graphics version: OpenGL ES 3.1 NVIDIA 343.00

05-24 13:38:28.620  5751  5777 E Unity   :  

05-24 13:38:28.620  5751  5777 E Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

05-24 13:38:28.620  5751  5777 E Unity   : 

05-24 13:38:28.667   617   794 D ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 100]

05-24 13:38:28.719  5751  5777 D Kudan   : KudanAR initialise called

05-24 13:38:28.721  5751  5777 D Kudan   : CameraPreviewAndRender initialise called

05-24 13:38:28.722  5751  5777 D Kudan   : OpenGL ES version is set to: 3

05-24 13:38:28.722  5751  5777 D Kudan   : OpenGL ES Can use glBindArray: true

05-24 13:38:28.722  5751  5777 D Kudan   : CameraPreviewAndRender loadShaders called

05-24 13:38:28.722  5751  5777 D Kudan   : CameraPreviewAndRender CreateTexture called

05-24 13:38:28.723  5751  5777 D Kudan   : CameraPreviewAndRender BindSinkTexture called

05-24 13:38:28.723  5751  5777 D Kudan   : CameraPreviewAndRender CreateShaderProgram called

05-24 13:38:28.752  5751  5777 D Kudan   : CameraPreviewAndRender SetupShaderProgram called

05-24 13:38:28.752  5751  5777 D Kudan   : CameraPreviewAndRender CreateQuadGeometry called

05-24 13:38:28.752  5751  5777 D Kudan   : StopTrackerThread called - bWaitForFinish: true

05-24 13:38:28.752  5751  5777 D Kudan   : StartTrackerThread: creating thread TrackerThread1464111508

05-24 13:38:28.754  5751  5777 D Kudan   : StartTrackerThread: Finished

05-24 13:38:28.767  5751  5777 I kudan-ndk: checking

05-24 13:38:28.782  5751  5751 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 5751 (eu.kudan.ar)

05-24 13:38:28.831   617   981 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{a426155 u0 SurfaceView}

05-24 13:38:28.832   617   654 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) InputDispatcher expire 2 lines

05-24 13:38:28.834   617   979 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{4004c13 u0 eu.kudan.ar/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}

05-24 13:38:28.834   617   979 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) Binder_7 expire 1 line

05-24 13:38:28.847   617   984 I ActivityManager: Process eu.kudan.ar (pid 5751) has died
```

Everything looks OK until the "kudan-ndk: checking" line. I am not a pro using Android but I did considered the "Gotchas" at the bottom of this turotial page : https://wiki.kudan.eu/Unity

I have installed Android API 22 using Android SDK manager since that level is stated as the targeted one. I have also forced screen orientation to be "landscape left" in player settings in Unity and I have even installed Android API 23 since my Nexus 9 has Android version 6.0.1. Maybe that last part is causing the problem... or not? Can anyone share a better understanding of this problem?

Comment: You'd be better off trying to contact them.

Comment: They say on their Web site that their developers are on Stack Overflow for support so I hope to cross one of them

Comment: Have you tried using the Unity v1.2 plugin from Kudan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have put new tutorials on the Kudan Wiki that should be much easier to follow. The ones helpful to you are called:
[My First Augmented Reality App (1.1.3 Stable)](https://wiki.kudan.eu/My_First_Augmented_Reality_App_(1.1.3_Stable))
[Building the App - Android](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Building_the_app_-_Android)

In response to your actual question, crash on start is generally caused by an incorrect API Key, which is set on the Kudan Camera. Ensure that this matches with its according Bundle ID, which is set in the player settings in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

```
F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 5751 (eu.kudan.ar)
```

I also had that error and it was because of a kudan marker, I replaced it with another one and it started working again.